# Should I use Docker to deploy a library of functions?

Tags: azure, docker

I see that Docker is intended to deploy applications, but what about libraries?  For instance I have a library called RAILWAY that is a set of headers, binary code libraries, and command line tools.

I was thinking the output of the railway CI/CD pipeline can be a docker image that is pushed to a registry.  Any application that wants to use railway, must be built using docker. And it will just put  `FROM railway:latest` and `COPY --from=railway ...` in its `Dockerfile`.  The application can copy whatever it need from the library image into its own image.

Is this a normal use-case?

I *could* use a Debian package for railway, but Azure Artifacts do not support Debian packages (only nuget and npm).  And docker is just so damn easy!

Answer (score 1):

Most languages have their own systems for distributing and managing dependencies (like NuGet which you mentioned) which you should use instead.

The problem with your suggestion is that it's not as simple as "applications use libraries", it's rather "applications use libraries which use libraries which use libraries which use...".

E.g. if your app wants to use libraries A and B, but library A also uses library B itself, how do you handle that in your setup? Is there a binary for B in As docker image that gets copied over?  Does it overwrite the binary for B that you copied earlier? What if they're different versions with different methods in them?